# Border Radius Implementation for Windows Phone in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currenly, I'm using this as reference [Border Radius](https://github.com/anubhavranjan/Entry-Renderer/blob/master/EntryRenderer/EntryRenderer.WinPhone/MyEntryRenderer.cs) for border radius but it seems like it's not working in my side. Does the Xamarin has a built in functionality for Border Radius Implementation?

Thanks in advance for the advice and help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know if did you use https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Frame/. Seems, it has standard little radius.

Also, I'd suggest you my workaround, that I used for Android and iOS(I understand, that it's not WP, but maybe it will do the same thing). I added `Button` on background and setted `BorderRadius`:

```
<Button BorderRadius="6"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        BorderColor="{StaticResource GreyColor}"
        BorderWidth="1"/>
```